# Retrieve the text from a JavaScript alert via Webdriver

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm creating a series of Webdriver tests which primary purpose are to ensure the validation of a web application page, so this revolves around ensuring the alert happens, but more importantly that the text displayed is correct and so the right validation is being triggered.

However I can't seem to get the text from the alerts.

I can't seem to find any info on retrieving the text from an alert and all research returns how to to simply accept the alert.

So far I have:

```
UnhandledAlertException alertText = UnhandledAlertException.GetAlertText();

Assert.That(alertText, Is.EqualTo("You must select the user's Primary Role"));
```

But "GetAlertText" isn't a thing recognized, I'm not sure if I need to get another file and reference it which contains this function or if it simply doesn't exist.

I was pretty sure there was a built in get alert text function but I appear to be wrong.

Thanks, 
-Tom

Comment: Where on earth did you get `UnhandledAlertException.GetAlertText();` from?

Comment: @Arran i think it was to make the question "legit" (because he tried "something") ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this Alert class.

```
public String getAlert()
{
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText = alert.getText();
    alert.accept();
    return alertText;
}
```

Will return the text message of Alert from java script Alert function.

If a alert is with some kind of js framework which looks like error but its popup then use xpath to get the text of that locator.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, and is exactly what I need, just its "IAlert" instead of "Alert", "SwitchTo" instead of "switchTo" and "alert.Text" not "alert.text", so: IAlert alert = _driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            String alertText = alert.Text;

 I'm not sure if I have slightly different webdriver references or they're typos, but thank you do much.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it worked. This will help others to refer from

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the alerts are JavaScripts, then it is possible to get the alert text as below

```
string alertText = ((OpenQA.Selenium.IAlert)driverObj).Text;
```